# Can every basis of a vector space be reduced to the standard basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the $n$-dimensional vector spaces $V\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Given a non-standard basis $B$ for the vector space $V$, can it be reduced to the standard basis on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: What do you mean by "reduce to the standard basis"?

Comment: @CameronBuie Sometimes a question comes from a conceptual mistake, and I think that's the case here - we are left with a question that still has conceptual mistakes, but hides what might be the key to unlocking the mistake.

Comment: @Thomas: Fair point. Rolled back. Hopefully the OP clarifies the question.

Comment: Chase, did you intend to say that $V\in\Bbb R^n$? This means that $V$ is an *element* of the canonical $n$-dimensional real vector space. It does *not* mean that $V$ is itself an $n$-dimensional real vector space. If you could clear this up, and answer Daniel's question, I think it would be a great deal easier to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any two bases of a vector space are equivalent, in the sense that there exists a linear transformation will map one basis to the other in a 1-to-1 mapping.

In fact one characterization of a basis is that any mapping of the basis to arbitrary vectors in a vector space determines a linear transformation.  So take one basis and assign distinct "standard basis vectors" to each element of that (non-standard) basis, and then this assignment extends by linearity to a linear transformation on the vector space as a whole.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I'll look into a proof now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In this constellation $V$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ are even isomorphic, because there is a uniquely determined linear map $f:V\to\mathbb{R}^n$, which has to be bijective due to the fact that we know a basis for both vector spaces - hence we can define a mapping $b_i\mapsto e_i$
for every $b_i\in B$, where $e_i$ is the $i-$th vector of the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Geometrically speaking it is only reasonable to say that $V$ in terms of $B$ can be "reduced" to $\mathbb{R}^n$ in terms of its standard basis, if $V=\mathbb{R}^n$, in the sense of $V$ (in the basis $B$) beeing an "odd version" version of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (in the standard basis). In any other case the two vector spaces have nothing in common than abstract properties. Think of $V$ beeing the vector space of polynomials. We know that, if $V$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ have the same dimension, they "must behave the same" (: be isomorphic) because of the existence of $f$; but it is impossible to say anything else.